# Calculate molecular mass from chemical formula C9H15N4O8P with Python?

Tags: python

Can I calculate the molecular mass from a formula like this `C9H15N4O8P` with Python e.g. using `rdkit`? I think `rdkit.Chem.Descriptors.MolWt` needs a molecule object. Though, to generate that I would need e.g. a SMILES string. Is there any other python module that can do the trick?

I found this: http://verahill.blogspot.com/2012/10/molecular-weight-calculator-in-python.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to adapt this approach within rdKit to calculate exact mass (for mass spectrometry), but was not successful.

This library (https://pypi.org/project/molmass/) appears to be able to do this:

```
from molmass import Formula
f = Formula('C7H11N3O2')
f.formula
f.isotope.mass
'169.08512660696'
```

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned, rdKit does not accept a chemical formula as input. The main reason for this are probably isomers. You could however use rdKit to initiate all the atoms, get their mass and add them together.

```
import re
from rdkit import Chem


def get_mass(formula):

    parts = re.findall("[A-Z][a-z]?|[0-9]+", formula)
    mass = 0

    for index in range(len(parts)):
        if parts[index].isnumeric():
            continue

        atom = Chem.Atom(parts[index])
        multiplier = int(parts[index + 1]) if len(parts) > index + 1 and parts[index + 1].isnumeric() else 1
        mass += atom.GetMass() * multiplier

    return mass
```

Then...

```
>>> get_mass("C9H15N4O8P")
338.21299999999997
```